# Count in Hasura subscription

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am new to GraphQL and Hasura. I have a table that has a "completed" field that is value can be true/false/null.
I am trying to count the total number of rows and the number of rows that is false in the  "completed" field

I tried the following:-

```
subscription MySubscription {
  total:  table_aggregate {
    aggregate {
      count
    }
  }
  incomplete: table_aggregate(where: {completed: {_eq: false}}) {
    aggregate {
      count(columns: completed)
    }
  }
}
```

but it dont work. Is it not possible in the case of subscription or what I am missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using `count` function wrong, change that line with the following: `count(column: "completed")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasura doesn't allow multiple top-level fields in a single subscription query. You'll need to create two separate subscriptions:

```
subscription TotalItems {
  table_aggregate {
    aggregate {
      count
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
subscription IncompleteItems {
  table_aggregate(where: {completed: {_eq: false}}) {
    aggregate {
      count
    }
  }
}
```